# edit style of jsf component primefaces

Tags: css, jsf-2, primefaces

I have this page :

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

    <body>

        <ui:composition template="./template_admin.xhtml">

            <ui:define name="tohead">
            </ui:define>

            <ui:define name="content">


                <p:panel header="Edition d'une commande"  style="height: 490px;" id="panel"  >
                    <p:messages id="msgs"/>
                    <h:panelGrid columns="3" style="float:left;" columnClasses="column" cellpadding="5">

                        <h:outputLabel  for="idd" value="Id : " />   
                        <p:inputText  disabled="true" value="#{editCommandController.myCom.id}" id="idd" required="true" requiredMessage="veuillez saisir un nom" label="Nom"  />  
                        <p:message for="idd" display="icon"/>

                        <h:outputLabel for="dteenvoi" value="Date d'envoi : " />  
                        <p:inputText disabled="true" id="dteenvoi" value="#{editCommandController.myCom.dateEnvoi}" required="true" requiredMessage="veuillez saisir un prénom" label="Prénom" />  
                        <p:message for="dteenvoi" display="icon"/>

                        <h:outputLabel for="division" value="Date de livraison recommandée : " />  
                        <p:inputText disabled="true"  id="division" value="#{editCommandController.myCom.dateLivraisonRecommande}" />  
                        <p:message for="division" display="icon"/>

                        <h:outputLabel for="poste" value="Nombre de page : " />  
                        <p:inputText id="poste" disabled="true" value="#{editCommandController.myCom.nbrePage}" />  
                        <p:message for="poste" display="icon"/>


                        <h:outputLabel for="email" value="Nombre d'exemplaire : " />  
                        <p:inputText id="email" disabled="true" value="#{editCommandController.myCom.nbreExemplaire}" />
                        <p:message for="email" display="icon"/>

                        <h:outputLabel for="autres" value="Type d'impression : " />  
                        <p:inputText id="autres" disabled="true" value="#{editCommandController.myCom.typeImpression}"  />  
                        <p:message for="autres" display="icon"/>

                        <h:outputLabel for="identifiant" value="Observation : " />  
                        <p:inputTextarea id="identifiant" disabled="true" value="#{editCommandController.myCom.observation}" required="true" validator="#{addUserController.validateIdentifiant}" requiredMessage="veuillez saisir un identifiant" label="Identifiant" />  
                        <p:message for="identifiant" display="icon"/>

                        <h:outputLabel for="dec" value="Decision : " />  
                        <p:selectOneMenu  id="dec" value="#{editCommandController.myCom.decision}" >  
                            <f:selectItems value="#{editCommandController.decisions}" />  
                            <p:ajax update="etat gridContainer :myform:alors" event="change" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>  
                        <p:message for="dec" display="icon"/>

                        <h:outputLabel for="etat" value="Etat : " />  
                        <p:selectOneMenu  id="etat" value="#{editCommandController.myCom.etat}" disabled="#{editCommandController.myCom.decision eq 'rejettée'}" >  
                            <f:selectItems value="#{editCommandController.etats}" />   
                        </p:selectOneMenu>  
                        <p:message for="etat" display="icon"/>

                        <h:outputLabel for="calen" value="Date de Livraison réelle: *" />
                        <p:calendar  label="Date de Livraison reelle" id="calen" showOn="button" effect="slide" value="#{editCommandController.myCom.dateLivraisonReelle}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" >
                        </p:calendar>  
                        <p:message for="calen" id="msgSurname4" display="icon"/>


                    </h:panelGrid>  

                    <p:outputPanel id="gridContainer" layoyut="block" >
                        <h:panelGrid id="alors"   rendered="#{editCommandController.myCom.decision ne 'rejettée'}" >
                            <p:dataTable id="cars" style="width: 80px;" var="car" value="#{editCommandController.pdm}" paginator="true" rows="10"  
                                         selection="#{editCommandController.selectedPapier}" selectionMode="single" >  

                                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{editCommandController.onRowSelect()}"   
                                        update=":myform:jesuis" />  

                                <f:facet name="header">  
                                    RadioButton Based Selection  
                                </f:facet>                    

                                <p:column headerText="libelle">  
                                    #{car.libelle}  
                                </p:column>  

                                <p:column headerText="format">  
                                    #{car.format}  
                                </p:column>  

                                <p:column headerText="stock" >  
                                    #{car.stock}  
                                </p:column>  

                            </p:dataTable>  


                            <h:outputText  id="jesuis" value=" c est la papier : #{editCommandController.selectedPapier.libelle}"  />


                            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5" style="margin-top: 22px;">  
                                <h:outputLabel value="Reliure :" for="city" />
                                <p:selectOneMenu id="city" value="#{addPapierController.choixReliure}">  
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="choisir reliure" itemValue="" />  
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{addPapierController.libelleReliures}" />  
                                    <p:ajax 
                                        listener="#{addPapierController.handleCityChange}" />  
                                </p:selectOneMenu>
                            </h:panelGrid>

                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </p:outputPanel>


                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="float:none;display: block;" >
                        <p:commandButton value="Editer" ajax="false" action="#{editCommandController.updateCommand()}" update="panel" ></p:commandButton>
                        <p:commandButton value="Annuler"  immediate="true" action="commandesUser" ajax="false" ></p:commandButton>

                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:panel>  

            </ui:define>

        </ui:composition>

    </body>
</html>
```

I would like to divide the panel into three part : 
the fisrt in the left of the page 
the second in the right of the page 
and the third in the bottom of the page

I managed to put the first and the second but the third part is just below the second part, I would like to put it only in the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first panel is floated left by `float:left;`. So anything which comes after it in the DOM will just end up on the right side of it as long as there's *at least some* vertical space for it. If you want the element to escape this float and thus end up in a new line, then you need to `clear` the float. This isn't to be done by `float:none;` as you attempted:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" style="float:none;display: block;" >
```

but instead by `clear:left;`:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" style="clear:left;" >
```

Note that I removed `display:block;` as the HTML `<table>` (as generated by `<h:panelGrid>` is *already* a [block level element](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/block.html).

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, this has very little to do with JSF. It's merely a HTML code generator. In future CSS-related questions it'd be more helpful for CSS experts if you ignore the JSF part and concentrate on its generated HTML output only (which you can find by rightclick, *View Source* in the webbrowser) in the question. Once you get the answer from the CSS experts, all you need to do is to trackback the responsible JSF component and change it accordingly so that you get the desired generated HTML output.

Comment: thank you BalusC, it works, you are right concerning your observation : this question concern css not jsf, it is been a long time I didn't read you, because I asked  several questions about jsf and you don't answer, I hope you are not angry with me

Comment: please, another question in the same topic : I would like to move the second part a little to the right, then I added this style : <p:outputPanel id="gridContainer" style="margin-left: 150px;" layoyut="block" >  but no result, how I can achieve this, thanks

Comment: Nothing personally. I usually just bypass questions which contain too much noise or are already answered (with a less or more reasonable answer) or are too localized.